# Way of summing all fields in rows with identical name in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm banging my head against a wall:
I'd like to add all values by row for all rows that have an identical value in the column 'fusion'. Here a dummy example:

```
import pandas as pd

rows_l = [['AFF1_KMT2A', 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4, 6.0],
 ['AFF1_KMT2A', 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3, 6.0],
 ['TCF3_PBX1', 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3, 5.0],
 ['TCF3_PBX1', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 1.0],
 ['ABL1_BCR', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4, 5.0]]
col_l = ['fusion', 'FusionCatcher', 'Manta', 'STARfusion', 'TopHat','tool_count', 'tot']

my_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_l, columns=col_l)
```

Gives me this my_df:

|  | fusion | FusionCatcher | Manta | STARfusion | TopHat | tool_count | tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABL1_BCR | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 4 | 5.0 |
| 1 | AFF1_KMT2A | 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 3 | 6.0 |
| 2 | TCF3_PBX1 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 3 | 5.0 |
| 3 | AFF1_KMT2A | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4 | 6.0 |
| 4 | TCF3_PBX1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1 | 1.0 |

Of course in my real file the identical lines are not always one line apart, but all over the place...

My output should look like this:

|  | fusion | FusionCatcher | Manta | STARfusion | TopHat | tool_count | tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AFF1_KMT2A | 6.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 7 | 12.0 |
| 1 | TCF3_PBX1 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4 | 6.0 |
| 2 | ABL1_BCR | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 4 | 5.0 |

So far I've only found `df['whatever_you_want_to_sum'].groupby(df['col_names_if_same_wil_be_bundled'])` but as this seems to work only for 2 columns that does not help me much.

Is there any particular `python pandas` way to do this or should I just continue to write my `for-loops` until the prints look right?

Comment: `my_df.groupby('fusion').sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using pivot tables?

```
pd.pivot_table(my_df, index="fusion", values=col_l, aggfunc=np.sum)
```

You also need to `import numpy as np` beforehand.
You get a pivot table as shown:[image]

Comment: I think [@Anurag Dabas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289892/anurag-dabas) has solved it [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789901/way-of-summing-all-fields-in-rows-with-identical-name-in-pandas-df#comment119821293_67789901), but I will try yours as well, thanks

Comment: Sure. Pivot tables are quite handy in these conditions. :) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Sorry, you need to put values=col_l instead of columns=col_l.